# If the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar, then are $AB$ and $BA$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n(F)$. Suppose that $n \geq 2$. Prove or disprove: If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $AB$ and $BA$ are similar.

I think that this statement is false. I tied to find A,B which are similar and not invertible which are $2 \times 2$ and are counterexample but I couldn't.  Would appreciate help to find any counterexample $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. Consider e.g. a field of characteristic $\ne2$ with
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0},
\ B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1},
\ AB=\pmatrix{0&2\\ 0&0}\ne0=BA.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the answer is positive for $2\times2$ matrices. If one of both matrices is invertible, then $AB$ and $BA$ are obviously similar. If one of both is $0_2$, this is obvious again. There remains the case
$$A=ab^T,\qquad B=uv^T,\qquad a,b,u,v\ne0.$$
(Since $A$ and $B$ are similar, we have $a\cdot b=u\cdot v$.) Then
$$AB=(b\cdot u)av^T,\qquad BA=(v\cdot a)ub^T,$$ which are similar for the same reason, that is ${\rm Tr}AB={\rm Tr}BA$. Notice that we don't need at all that $A$ and $B$ be similar !

Comment: And for 3X3 matrices?

Comment: If you're wondering why this answer is not correct, it's due to the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are similar, then their trace is equal, but the inverse is not true in general (as the answer by user1551 clearly shows).